# How to call/initiate Android onResume from JavaScript/ or a Cordova plug-in?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, ibm-mobilefirst, cordova-plugins

```
1. Javascript file ------ calls -------> CORDOVA PLUGIN(plugin.java)
2. CORDOVA PLUGIN(plugin.java) file -------calls-------> Android BroadcastReceiver file(Broadcast_Receiver.java)
```

Broadcast_Receiver.java contains onResume.
How do I call/initiate it from Javascript file?

*Please see sample code at the bottom*

Problem #1: I can't combine plugin.java & Broadcast_Receiver.java because they are extending CordovaPlugin & WLDroidGap respectively.

Problem #2: When I navigate between pages of my worklight application; onResume of Broadcast_Receiver.java never gets triggered because onResume is in native Android code

Possible solution which i was unable to implement:

1. use cordova onResume i.e.: `document.addEventListener("resume", function() { });`
2. merge plugin.java & Broadcast_Receiver.java

In short: how to initiate android lifecycle using a Cordova plug-in?

**Sample code**

**Javascript file calls plugin**

```
    //some code
    currentPage.myfunction= function() {
        cordova.exec(Success, Failure, "plugin","someMETHOD", []);
}
```

**plugin.java**

```
public class plugin extends CordovaPlugin
{
//some code

    float value= Broadcast_Receiver.Variable_Name;

//some code
}
```

**Broadcast_Receiver.java**

```
public class roamingadvisor extends WLDroidGap {

//some code

onCreate(){}
onResume(){}
onPause(){}


//some code
}
```

**What I am trying to achieve**
My application starts calculating data usage once it receives broadcast that data got activated

1. I am able to calculate data usage
   It gets updated once i press home button & relaunch my app(i.e. trigger native onResume in android)
2. But when i keep using my application (i.e navigate between UI screen) native android onResume never gets triggered

Or

should i do it using entirely different approach?

```
*******R&D *******
```

I used below two link

```
https://apache.googlesource.com/cordova-android/+/2.6.x/framework/src/org/apache/cordova/Device.java
https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/master/framework/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaPlugin.java
```

and wrote follwing code for my need

```
public class Myclass extends CordovaPlugin {



    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE");
    boolean multitasking=true;
    BroadcastReceiver mReceiver=null;

    //constructor
    public MyDataUsage(){

    }


    public void initialize(CordovaInterface cordova, CordovaWebView webView) {

        super.initialize(cordova, webView);
        //Device.uuid = getUuid();
        this.initReceiver();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause(boolean multitasking) {

        super.onPause(multitasking);
        this.cordova.getActivity().unregisterReceiver(this.mReceiver);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(boolean multitasking) {

        super.onResume(multitasking);
        this.cordova.getActivity().registerReceiver(this.mReceiver, intentFilter);
    }



    public void onDestroy() {

        this.cordova.getActivity().unregisterReceiver(this.mReceiver);
    }


    private void initReceiver() {

        this.mReceiver=new BroadcastReceiver(){

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                ctb=context;
                if (intent.getAction().equals("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"))
                        {
                //My code


                }



            }
            }

        };

        this.cordova.getActivity().registerReceiver(this.mReceiver, intentFilter);
    }



    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray arr,
            final CallbackContext callbackcontext) throws JSONException {


        if (action.equals("getDataUsage")) {

            try {
                 //code
                callbackcontext.success(""+dataUsed+ ":" +timeElapsed+":"+StartTime);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                callbackcontext.error("ERROR :");
            }

            return true;
        }

        return false;

    }

}
```

But onPause & onResume still gets called only when i press HOME key & RELAUNCH  my APP

```
Should i CONCLUDE that " I can not implement ACTIVITY LIFECYCLE while naviagting in my UI/html SCREEN/pages" ???
```

Comment: @Idan thanks for making my query/question more clear & understandable

Comment: @IDAN please see my code after ****R&D******
and Should i CONCLUDE that " I can not implement ACTIVITY LIFECYCLE while naviagting in my my UI/html SCREEN/pages" ???
Please do reply

Answer (score 4):

By default Cordova application consist of a single Activity which hosts a single WebView. When you're navigating pages/changing content in web you will not get any lifecycle events from Activity because technically you're still in a context of a same Activity.

Note that CordovaPlugin class has callbacks for many Activity lifecycle methods, you can leverage them (https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/master/framework/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaPlugin.java). For example use initialize() method for starting your calculation and onDestroy() method to detect when your app is being closed. You can also use other CordovaPlugin methods such as onResume() and onPause() according to the logic you're trying to implement.

Comment: Thanks for clarification on "Cordova application Activity"

Query Regarding CordovaPlugin: can i trigger onPause in cordovaplugin when i NAVIGATE to different UI/PAGE/SCREEN ?